# Comparing strings lexicographically

Tags: c++, string, compare

I thought that if I used operators such as ">"  and "<" in c++ to compare strings, these would compare them lexicographically, the problem is that this only works sometimes in my computer.
For example

```
if("aa" > "bz") cout<<"Yes";
```

This will print nothing, and thats what I need, but If I type

```
if("aa" > "bzaa") cout<<"Yes";
```

This will print "Yes", why is this happening? Or is there some other way I should use to compare strings lexicographically?

Comment: The problem is that "aa" and "bz" are not *string* s. It's time to tell tutorial authors and teachers to call *the thing between the ""* as "textual literal" and not "string". It will remove the most of confusion and headache in newbies!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Comparing `std::string` -s like that **will** work. However you are comparing string literals. To do the comparison you want either initialize a std::string with them or use strcmp:

```
if(std::string("aa") > std::string("bz")) cout<<"Yes";
```

This is the c++ style solution to that.

Or alternatively:

```
if(strcmp("aa", "bz") > 0) cout<<"Yes";
```

EDIT(thanks to Konrad Rudolph's comment): in fact in the first version only one of the operands should be converted explicitly so:

```
if(std::string("aa") > "bz") cout<<"Yes";
```

Will again work as expected.

EDIT(thanks to churill's comment): since c++14 you can use string literals:

```
if("aa"s > "bz") cout<<"Yes";
```

Comment: Only one operand needs to be converted explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, thats all I needed to know.

Comment: I'd like to add that, since C++14 you can write it even shorter with [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator""s) -> `if("aa"s > "bz")`.

Comment: @churill thank you for this addition I have reflected this in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You are comparing "primitive" strings, which are of type `char const *`.

The following is essentially equivalent to your example:

```
char const * s1 = "aa";
char const * s2 = "bz";
if ( s1 > s2 ) cout<<"Yes";
```

This is comparing the pointers (the memory addresses of the strings), not the contents.

@izomorphius has suggested some good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strcmp()` function which is included in the `#include <cstring>` header file. `strcmp()` compares the two strings character by character. The process will continue until it reaches `NULL` or one of the strings become unequal (characters become unequal).
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


void display(char *lhs, char *rhs, int result)
{
    if(result > 0)
        std::cout << rhs << " precedes " << lhs << std::endl;
    else if (result < 0)
        std::cout << lhs << " precedes " << rhs << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << lhs << " and " << rhs << " are same" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    char lhs[] = "aa";
    char rhs[] = "bz";
    int result;

    result = strcmp(lhs,rhs);
    display(lhs,rhs,result);

    result = strcmp(lhs,lhs);
    display(lhs,lhs,result);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
aa precedes bz
aa and aa are same
```